# Symfony 6 - Problem with creating a bundle for symfony 6 to add new commands to the symfony console

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony6, packagist

I am a newer in packagist development.

I made two commands to make documents ands cruds on my symfony6 project for mongo Documents (with auto documentation from nelmio-api-bundle).

Now I use this commands in many projects and I want to create a bundle to make the modifications on these commands easier in all my projects.

So, I created a project, using the symfony documentation for create a bundle. I pushed it on github, then and I created a package successfully on packagist.

I can require my bundle using composer require ama/symfony-mongo-maker-bundle:dev-main but when i call my commands (ex: symfony console make:document), I have an error :

"  There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace. ".

It's my first and very small crash-test bundle project. I haven't been able to find the solution in the Symfony documentation or in the examples from other bundles, as they are all so different from each other. I would be truly grateful if someone could show me the way.

[My bundle repository here](https://gitlab.com/AlexandraMasvidal/mongomaker/-/tree/main?ref_type=heads)
[My package link here](https://packagist.org/packages/ama/symfony-mongo-maker-bundle)

Thank you :)

I tried many configurations in services.yaml, re-make my bundle from scratch, clear composer...

Comment: I looked at your repo and this is just a guess but because you are using the AbstractBundle class I don't think your extension is being called.  Check the docs and see how to move the extension code directly into your bundle.  Plus you really should not need to override AbstractBundle::getPath. Here is a [working example](https://github.com/cerad/s62bundle/blob/main/src-my-bundle/src/CeradMyBundle.php).  Maybe it will help.

Comment: This by the way is a classic example of why you should include the relevant code in your question as opposed to just linking to a repo.  You have updated the repo several times already.  Hopefully things are now working but it makes your question pretty much useless to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Cerad, yes I changed my code on my repo but only after it finally worked, thanks to your example and the symfony documentation ! The problem was in my bundle file, exactly as you suggested. htank you very much ! :). The working bundle is now on a new repo that I hope maintain for years : https://gitlab.com/AlexandraMasvidal/ama-symfony-mongo-maker. Be sure I will publish my code in my next questions ;)